# The hookrightarrow and its meaning

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Very weirdly I found a $\hookrightarrow $ in my Algebra book just like that. Could someone please just tell me what it means? Sorry for this maybe stupid question in advance but very much appreciate your help!

Comment: Most probably, it denotes an injective morphism.

Comment: It's used between groups at this point... pretty weird it wasn't explained before using it.

Comment: Between groups, I'm sure.

Comment: $A\hookrightarrow B$ primarily means the usual inclusion if $A\subseteq B$, i.e. the restriction of the identity function. More generally, it can also denote arbitrary *embedding*, which, in algebraic context, is usually the same as 'injective homomorphism'.

Comment: thanks guys for your help! much appreciated here :)

Answer (score 12):

Resolved in comments, so I'll make this community wiki. $F \hookrightarrow G$ denotes the inclusion of $F$ in $G$, with $\hookrightarrow$ denoting a monomorphism.

Answer (score 7):

In an algebraic setting, $\hookrightarrow$ denotes a monic map and $\twoheadrightarrow$ denotes an epic map.